# "Due to a technical error the e-ticket cannot be shown" error with Turkish Airlines. Anything I can do to view my reservation?

Tags: turkish-airlines

I'm trying to get into my Turkish Airlines reservation and I'm seeing the error on their website:

> Due to a technical error the e-ticket cannot be shown.

If I try the mobile app, I'm seeing the error:

> There has been a schedule change on your flight. Please contact our sales office or call center to confirm or to request a change and refund.

Is there a workaround that would let me see the latest status of my reservation, short of calling them? The current phone support waiting time is 27 minutes and in my experience the line often disconnects before you get a chance to speak to a human.

Comment: If I were you I would just count myself lucky that the wait time is as short as that and keep the phone on speaker while I cooked my dinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I was able to get through their phone support and figured out what was wrong with my ticket. Turns out, Turkish Airlines have an annoying system where if your ticket time is changed by even 5 minutes they force you to call them to confirm or cancel the ticket rather than having a convenient button on their website. However I've asked the phone support guy if I can avoid making the call (as I'm not 100% sure if I want to confirm or cancel) and he told me I can email one of their ticketing offices instead.

You can find their [list of sales offices here](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/get-in-touch/) - select the country where your flight is departing or arriving and you should see their local office email there. If your city doesn't have a ticket sales office, just choose the closest city nearby. For some reason they don't have a central email address you can reach out to. After emailing the local sales office I was able to receive a response within just a few hours and they were happy to help me reschedule the flight.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did Amadeus work, or did TK yank your itinerary entirely?

Comment: @lambshaanxy it was yanked entirely. Adding the flight using the reservation code didn't work. Adding it by forwarding the reservation email worked but it didn't show the full itinerary correctly so I presume it was indeed yanked.

Answer (score 3):

Turkish Airlines uses Amadeus, so you should be able to pull up your itinerary by entering your PNR/record locator into Checkmytrip:

https://www.checkmytrip.com/cmtweb/

However, it sounds to me like they've cancelled your flight, so you will likely need to suffer through the phone call anyway.  Good luck!